# How to include a colon in specific command sudoers entry?

Tags: sudo, quoting

I need to add an entry to the sudoers file to allow the user to run a specific command. So it happens the command includes a colon " : "

```
mount -t nfs -o vers=4 host:/remoteMountpoint /home/username/localMountpoint
```

Visudo complains the entry is not valid, doesn't allow me to save it. I mean I could try and force it but I am afraid of the consequences. One obvious workaround is to use a wildcard " * " in place of the colon, but I wonder if there's another (proper) way to do it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the [sudoers man page](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.17/sudoers.man.html):

> Note that the following characters must be escaped with a ‘\’ if they are used in command arguments: `,`, `:`, `=`, `\`.

```
mount -t nfs -o vers\=4 host\:/remoteMountpoint /home/username/localMountpoint
```