# sudoers syntax error near line 1 while adding cmnd alias

Tags: linux, debian, sudo, cd-command, sudoedit

I am attempting to modify the sudoers files located within the sudoers.d directory to allow a group named "**swts**" to perform a cp and chown as part of an automation job. To accomplish this, I created a Cmnd_Alias as follows and saved in file called `/etc/sudoers.d/00-cmds-swts`:

```
Cmnd_Alias SWTS_COMMANDS = /usr/bin/cp -r * /home/bbc/leo/BQD*, /bin/chown -R bbc:bbc /home/bbc/leo/BQD*
```

However, when using visudo to edit the file and attempting to save, I receive the following error:

```
>>> 00-cmds-qa: syntax error near line 1 <<<
```

I am not sure what I am missing. Is it something with the source for the cp command?

I finally utilized the command alias in another file under `/etc/sudoers.conf/swts-users` which has below contents:

```
%swts ALL=(bbc:bbc) NOPASSWD: SWTS_COMMANDS
```

Comment: Welcome to U&L. Troubleshooting a syntax error near line 1 in `sudoers` file is somewhat difficult without seeing the offending part. So maybe you could [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/736634/edit) the question and add the file? Please use the code brackets `{ }` around the output to preserve formatting.

Comment: Thanks @Peregrino69 for the comment. I got what's bugging me. I am adding the answer in comments.

Comment: Great, don't forget to drop back to accept your answer so this doesn't pop up in the future as "Unanaswered" - you'll need to wait for 48 hours, tho' :-) However as these are Q/A sites and very easily show up in top of for example Google searches, it'd be good to have the question complete with the contents of the problematic file. That also makes your answer more useful in the future.

Comment: as a good practice, i was not editing /etc/sudoers file, rather I was adding the configurations for each group in different files. For example, swts users, the commands file is 00-swts-commands with Cmnd_Alias and file swts-users contain the main configuration.

Comment: LOL you're just making this better :-D So the exact file under `/etc/sudoers.conf/swts-users` is `00-swts-commands`? I'm learning here :-)

Comment: `/etc/sudoers.conf/swts-users`  and `/etc/sudoers.conf/00-cmds-swts` are two files. The later one has the Command Alias. The first one utilizes this command alias. This way I can edit only the second file If I want to add one more command.

Comment: Thanks for the teachings :-)

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/356421/117549

Answer (score 3):

I found that special character `:` in the `sudoers` file must be escaped if used within the command. So, in my example, the offending part was the `:` in the `chown` command.

```
/bin/chown -R bbc:bbc /home/bbc/leo/BQD*
```

I replaced it with the one below, and it worked.

```
/bin/chown -R bbc\:bbc /home/bbc/leo/BQD*
```